# What are for square brackets in an addressed-of pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, embedded, memory-address, flags

I've been searching for a while what are for square-brackets in an addressed-of pointer, but I continue without understanding it. Here are the lines of the function, where "id" variable is an uint32_t pointer that has been previously passed as an argument.

```
#define LIST_STARTED (0x0001) /*defined out of the function*/
#define LIST_FIRST   (0x0002) /*defined out of the function*/

uint32_t *pointer = id;
uint16_t *flags = &((uint16_t *)pointer)[0];
uint16_t *index = &((uint16_t *)pointer)[1];
bool started = *flags & LIST_STARTED;
bool first   = *flags & LIST_FIRST;

if (!started){
    /* does something */
    *flags = MSEC_PRM_MGMT_LIST_STARTED;
    return true;
}
if (!first){
    /* does something */
    *flags |= MSEC_PRM_MGMT_LIST_FIRST;
    *index = 1;
    return true;
}
if (*index == final_index)
    /* does something */
    return false;

*index += 1;
```

I understand what the logic of the function is, but I don't understand what do the following lines. I put "all" the code above in case it helps you.

```
uint16_t *flags = &((uint16_t *)pointer)[0];
uint16_t *index = &((uint16_t *)pointer)[1];
```

I would appreciate if someone could help me!
Thank you!

I edit to say that this C code works fine in an Embedded System, I'm not modifying it, I was just watching its behaviour.

Comment: Shouldn't `uint32_t *pointer = id;` be `uint32_t *pointer = &id;` ? Please post the declaration of `id` so that the question can be answered.

Comment: @Lundin from the text `Here are the lines of the function, where "id" variable is an uint32_t pointer that has been previously passed as an argument.` I would say `id` has the type `uint32_t *` or `void *`.

Comment: @mch In that case, post how the function is called. A [mcve]. This whole code may or may not be a strict aliasing violation.

Comment: ID is uint32_t *id;

Comment: @Nkolot And points to where?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code tries to read a `uint32_t` object as an array of two `uint16_t` objects:

```
uint32_t *id = ...;
uint32_t *pointer = id;
uint16_t *flags = &((uint16_t *)pointer)[0];
uint16_t *index = &((uint16_t *)pointer)[1];
```

and that is undefined behaviour to read a `uint32_t` object as 2 `uint16_t` objects through `flags` and `index` pointers because that breaks strict aliasing rules.

The correct way is:

```
uint16_t flags = *id; // The lowest order bits of id.
uint16_t index = *id >> 16; // The highest order bits of id.
```

In the above assignments of `uint32_t` to `uint16_t` it truncates the highest order bits of `id`.

Comment: The C code doesn't break, it is already working in an embedded system. I am just seeing the code, not modifying it. Anyway, although you have not resolved my doubts, thanks for the answer.

Comment: You can't say that this is a strict aliasing violation without knowing the type of `id`. If anything, `uint32_t *pointer = id;` looks like a constraint violation error that shouldn't compile.

Comment: @Nkolot _it is already working in an embedded system_ doesn't mean that it won't break when you change compiler, optimization options or refactor your code. The correct version is no less performant.

Comment: There's lots of sloppy compilers which would let it compile with a warning, including gcc.

Comment: Instead of id being uint32_t I would like you to think about being uint16_t. in that case what is uint16_t *flags = &(pointer)[0]; or uint16_t *index = &(pointer)[1]; for? Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1):

```
uint32_t *pointer = id;
uint16_t *flags = &((uint16_t *)pointer)[0];
```

it is an equivalent of.

```
uint32_t *pointer = id;
uint16_t *flags = (uint16_t *)pointer;
```

The definition:

```
uint16_t *index = &((uint16_t *)pointer)[1];
```

Is an equivalent of:

```
uint16_t *temp = (uint16_t *)pointer;
uint16_t *index = temp + 1;
//or
uint16_t *index = &temp[1];
```

This is called: pointer punning and it is considered dangerous and not portable.

You can use unions for safe punning (at least when using gcc or its derivatives)

```
typedef union
{
    uint64_t u64;
    uint32_t u32[2];
    uint16_t u16[4];
    uint8_t u8[8];
    struct
    {
        uint8_t n1: 4;
        uint8_t n2: 4;
    }u4[8];
}union_pune_t;


uint16_t foo16(uint32_t *p32)
{
    union_pune_t *d64 = (void *)p32;

    return d64 -> u16[1];
}

uint8_t foo8(uint32_t *p32)
{
    union_pune_t *d64 = (void *)p32;

    return d64 -> u8[5];
}

uint8_t foon4(uint32_t *p32)
{
    union_pune_t *d64 = (void *)p32;

    return d64 -> u4[9].n2;
}
```

Comment: `u4[16]` generates at best 16 bytes of data, so maybe skip that one.

Comment: Also regarding portability, unions mean endianess-dependent code, so this isn't truly portable either. And I'm not sure if this code actually solves the strict aliasing issue, since you can't go between `uint32_t*` and the union type unless the effective type of the actual data is compatible with one of the union member types. If it is something else, like a custom struct, then this code won't be safe either.

Comment: @Lundin they do not generate 16 bytes of data on gcc, ARM compiler, IAR compiler, GHC

Comment: Yes they do...(4+4 bits = 1 byte, 1 x 16 = 16) https://godbolt.org/z/9dvhsa.